how to clean a model after the related models inline forms have been saved in the admin site in the transaction start?
I have such models:
class Advert(CreatedUpdatedMixin):
    ...
    use_pickup = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_('pickup'),
        default=False,
    )
    use_nova_post = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_('nova post'),
        default=False,
    )
    use_courier = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=_('courier'),
        default=True,
    )
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if not any([self.use_pickup, self.use_nova_post, self.use_courier]):
            raise ValidationError(
                _('One of next field must be true: use_pickup, use_nova_post, use_courier.'),
                'invalid_use_fields',
            )
        if self.use_pickup and getattr(self, 'address', None) is None:
            raise ValidationError(
                _('Address must be specified if use_pickup field is true.'),
                'empty_address',
            )



class AdvertAddress(Address):
    advert = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('advert'),
        to=Advert,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='address',
    )

When I save a Advert model in the admin site, there is error from this part code:
if self.use_pickup and getattr(self, 'address', None) is None:
    raise ValidationError(
        _('Address must be specified if use_pickup field is true.'),
        'empty_address',
    )

because admin form check clear before saving advert and advert address. The only thing that came to mind was to modify changeform_view. Maybe there exists some another way.
